# How to run a graphical app before console login in a systemd-nspawn'd container?

Tags: boot, systemd-startup

TL;DR **I'm looking for a way to autostart graphical applications, without first requiring the user to manually login.**
I'm improving my [Vdesktop script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=251757) that runs multiple versions of Raspbian on one Pi simultaneously using systemd-nspawn.

I am working towards building a GUI tool that manages SD cards and image files, as well as booting them.
The only hindrance to a GUI tool able to 'boot' a Raspbian image is the bothersome manual console login.
[image]
I'm looking for a way to autostart graphical applications, without first requiring the user to manually login.
Either getting the console to autologin (I've tried, I failed), or finding an autostart method that can run lxsession in the foreground, with no need for console login first.

I'd like to stay away from having the script automatically type in 'pi', and 'raspberry', because Vdesktop must work properly on a system whose Pi password has been changed.

Comment: Why is lightdm.sevice not starting? Can you edit the lightdm configuration to connect to the Xephyr server?

Comment: I doubt there is a silver bullet here. The two solutions I'm aware of (lightdm/agetty) are already mentioned, and I would try to understand why they don't work in nspawnd container rather than hoping to find yet another one.

Comment: I think it comes down to the container not having a /dev/tty0. Because when I run /usr/sbin/lightdm, it errors `Error opening /dev/tty0: No such file or directory`. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try `machinectl bind NAME /dev/sometty /dev/tty0`, assuming you have an unused `sometty` device on the host system? Or symlink `/dev/console` to `/dev/tty0` inside the container?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I tried creating a symlink /dev/vconsole to /dev/tty0, but now lightdm says `Error using VT_ACTIVATE 7 on /dev/tty0: Inappropriate ioctl for device`.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but what I've done in the past is to first set up an auto-login service for the user account that would run the application:

sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin app_user %I $TERM
```

Then in the user .profile, start an X session:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```

Lastly, in the user X init file (.xinitrc) start the GUI application:

```
exec python gui_app.py
```

This may not be the best way, but it worked for me on an application that only had a graphic display and didn't require (or have) any user input.  Note that this setup does rely on systemd.

Comment: Yes, this works on a Pi. For some reason not on a systemd virtual machine. Raspbian already has `autologin@.service` by default.

Comment: @Botspot What is a systemd virtual machine? You do not use a Raspberry Pi that would be a systemd real machine?

Comment: @Ingo good question. I have developed a [script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=251757) that uses [systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) to 'boot' a raspbian virtual machine on a Raspberry Pi. A way to run several OS'es at once for testing, development, comparison, backups, compiling in a disposable OS, etc.

Comment: [Vdesktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=251757) takes a Raspbian .img file, and boots it inside a VNC-style window.

Comment: @Botspot Ah.. systemd-nspawn. That's container technology, all running on the current kernel, not virtualisation. That was confusing me a bit.

Comment: @Ingo, Sorry for the confusion. Yes I know it is not technically a virtual machine, since nothing is virtualized. But to an average beginning user, I can't think of a better  term to help them understand. Terminology suggestions welcome. And feel free to try out Vdesktop and see if you can find a way to bypass the login.

Comment: @Botspot No problem, it was only for my understanding because you don't mention it in the question. I have only skimmed the thread you have linked, tl;dr. And sorry, I just don't have a desktop available on my RasPi. I'm one of the guys loving the command line on a black and white console ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm convinced that your problems stem from the fact that regular autologin methods rely on a real tty being available, while your guest system will have none (it will only have `/dev/console` which kind of emulates a terminal using stream redirection and the like, depending on the `--console` parameter of `nspawnd`). You don't seem to be able to start an X server on that, which is not surprising since it's not a real screen, so you need the guest system to use the X server of the host system which has already started.

The command line autologin should still work though. Perhaps you need to specify `/dev/console` as a terminal for `agetty` (instead of `$TERM`), or perhaps provide the guest system with a pseudo terminal (check out the -S option of `xterm` for instance).

You likely won't be able to run `startx` directly from this console, but the [XDMCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)#X_Display_Manager_Control_Protocol) protocol may do the trick. It should let your guest X server use the screen of the host system. On your host, you need to enable XDMCP support. Add the following to your `lightdm.conf` and restart:

```
    [XDMCPServer]
    enabled=true
    port=177
```

Make a virtual networking interface between host and guest using `--network-veth` parameter of `nspawnd`, then inside your host system start the X server with

```
X -query HOST_IP
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try this yet, but this answer looks helpful. Bounty granted, and I will report my progress.

Comment: @Botspot I wouldn't vouch it will work, but at least it's something you haven't tried yet.